# Detect if script has already loaded or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, internet-explorer-8, getscript

It seems that `helloworld.js` gets loaded multiple times based on the number of times I click `#load`.  I say this because when I look at Google Chromes Developer Tools Network tab, it shows `helloworld.js` as many times as I click `#load`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#load").click(function(){
        $.getScript('helloworld.js', function() {
            hello();
        });
    });

});
```

The `hello()` function looks like this:

```
function hello(){
    alert("hello");
}
```

Is it possible to detect if `helloworld.js` has already loaded?

So if it hasn't loaded, load it, and if it has loaded, don't load it.

This is what Developer Tools currently shows me if I click the `#load` button 4 times:

[image]

Comment: You can also let it use cache: `$.ajaxSetup({ cache: true });` (taken from [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/)).

Comment: The calls should be cached already by the browser…

Comment: @ShadowWizard, this seems to work, thanks.  It should be an answer.

Comment: @feeela by default jQuery will add unique timestamp to each AJAX call so that it won't get cached. By setting the property to *false* it won't add any unique value.

Comment: @feeela `$.getScript` is the exception, it defaults to `cache:false` unless specifically set in `ajaxSetup`. (per the documentation)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another option is letting `.getScript()` run but let it take the script from browser's cache so you won't have it reloaded each and every time.

To achieve this, add such code:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    cache: true
});
```

This is taken from the [documentation page](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/).

Comment: If the script file has some event binding code wouldn't the event bind multiple times, each time the file is loaded or taken from the cache?

Comment: @Reddy that is true, didn't think of it. My answer is an alternative to [this other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13382092/447356), which advice to use the `.one()` which I must admit is better in this case.

Comment: no problem in your answer at all. Was just curious to know, Because I have a issue where I load a html page which has local scripts within it and the events are binding multiple times. Just wanted to know if it is the same when read from cache.

Comment: @Reddy yeah, it will probably bind them again indeed, though it's worth checking in depth.

Answer (score 10):

Set a flag when file loaded successfully. If flag is set then skip the file loading again.

Try this code,

```
    var isLoaded = 0; //Set the flag OFF 

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#load").click(function(){
            if(isLoaded){ //If flag is ON then return false
                alert("File already loaded");
                return false;
            }
            $.getScript('helloworld.js', function() {
                isLoaded = 1; //Turn ON the flag
                hello();

            });
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 8):

So why not only fire the event once like this:

```
$("#load").one("click", function() {
   $load = $(this);
   $.getScript('helloworld.js', function() {
       hello();
       // bind hello to the click event of load for subsequent calls
       $load.on('click', hello); 
   });
});
```

That would prevent subsequent loads and avoids the use of a global

Comment: And to add, use `$("#load").click(hello)` after `hello()` to make subsequent clicks to `#load` call the `hello` method without re-loading the js.

Comment: @Gabe, I need to run the `hello()` function many times, but need to load the `helloworld.js` only once.

Answer (score 3):

You could create a helper function:

```
var getScript = (function() {
  var loadedFiles = {};
  return function(filename, callback) {
    if(loadedFiles[filename]) {
      callback();
    } else {
      $.getScript(filename, function() {
        loadedFiles[filename] = true;
        callback();
      });
    }
  };
})();
```

Comment: Implementing such a cache system is not that trivial. For instance, what if `getScript` is invoked multiple times for the same file name *before* the file in question is retrieved and executed?

Comment: @Šime Vidas: Good point. On the other hand, that would only happen if you click multiple times very fast after each other, which may not be worth caring about.

Comment: As both my parents regularly double-click on buttons, and links on web-pages, I think this scenario would occur more often than you think `:P`